# How to make cross table in p:dataTable primefaces jsf?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I must make p:dataTable which have 6 columns and 3 permanent rows. Each of the row must have own name, it will be in first column and in the others columns, cells can be editing but this is not a problem. Is anybody know how to make that kind of table? I tried with p:panelGrid but it can't be editable. I post sample picture of that table. Thank you!

http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/6823/v94s.gif

Comment: Build the table manually and use `<ui:repeat>` to help creating each row.

Comment: Thanks for replay! Can you be more specyfic? How to use <ui:repeat> to create in my case 3 steable rows? Some kind of example?It will be really easier to me.

Comment: You may search for examples in your favorite SEO e.g. google.

Comment: I have been searching a lot but example in my case is hard to find. So I ask you:)